# Creating Unsigned Invisible Signature field Using Itextsharp version 5 C#

Tags: c#, itext, digital-signature, electronic-signature

I need to create multiple unsigned signature field that are invisible in pdf. Can anyone help me in this? I am using pdfstamper (Itextsharp v5) for creating new signature. I can able to append multiple digital signature in a same pdf but i need to append multiple unsigned invisible signature..

Comment: A signature field is *invisible* if it has a 0x0 rectangle, or if its **Hidden** (or probably its **Invisible**) flag is set, or if it is not associated with any page. Which kind of invisibility are you after?

Comment: Thanks.. I put 0*0 rectangle and got invisible signature